# Use request.session as the success_url in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a CBV that I need to pass a request.session variable to as the success_url. I have not been able to implement this. May somebody help, please.

```
class UpdateTeacherIssueView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):       
    model = TeacherIssue
    form_class = UpdateTeacherIssueForm
    template_name = 'crud_forms/edit_teacher_issue.html'
    success_url =reverse_lazy('all', path = selected_item>)
```

In function based views it would be, `selected_item = request.session.get('item'`)
How is the same possible in CBV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write getter for success URL like

```
def get_success_url(self):
   return '/<your url>/'+self.request.session.get('item')
```

it will overwrite success URL

Comment: Thank you. This is the actual url I want it to go back to on success. path('borrowed/teacher/<path:borrowed>',views.all_borrowed_teacher,name='all_borrowed_teacher'), I don't absorb how to put it

Comment: def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    return kwargs['borrowed']

but for better coding you can put it as ?next=borrowed in get request

def get_success_url(self):
    return self.request.GET.get('next',<default url if not next>)